# WPF XCEED DataGrid multiple property in one column

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a class which has two level of collections. The software is about salaries payment. The idea is a payment action consists of multiple paid employees. And each employees could have multiple salaries cuts. The Object would look like:

```
Payment -->Payment Object
  Date
  ID
  Employees: -->ObservableCollection of EmpPayment Objects
     Emp A   -->And EmpPayment Object
        Name
        TotalCut --> An Integer Readonly Property that sums the Cuts.
        Cuts   --> Collection of Cut object
           Cut1  --> Cut object 1
           Cut2  --> Cut object 2
     Emp B
        Name
        TotalCuts
        Cuts
           Cut1
           Cut2
```

I am using a exceed DataGrid. So far so good except I want to display two values in one column using CellContentTemplate, that is the Cuts and the TotalCut. So the datagrid will look like:

```
Employee | Cuts
Emp A    | [The Total Cut]
           Cut 1
           Cut 2
Emp B    | [The Total Cut]
           Cut 1
           Cut 2
```

At the cuts column, i want to use a Xceed DropDownButton to show the total, and user can edit the cuts by editting the dropdowncontent. So far the XAML i made for the Employees ObservableCollection:

```
<xcdg:DataGridControl x:Name="GridEmployees" ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}" AutoCreateColumns="False">
    <xcdg:DataGridControl.Columns>
        <xcdg:Column FieldName="Name" Title="Employee"/>

        <xcdg:Column FieldName="Cuts" Title="Cuts">
            <xcdg:Column.CellContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <xctk:DropDownButton Content="{Binding Path=TOTALCUT}">
                        <xctk:DropDownButton.DropDownContent>
                            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <TextBox Text="{Binding CutDescription}"/>
                                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Amount}"/>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListBox>
                        </xctk:DropDownButton.DropDownContent>
                    </xctk:DropDownButton>
                </DataTemplate>
            </xcdg:Column.CellContentTemplate>
        </xcdg:Column>

    </xcdg:DataGridControl.Columns>
</xcdg:DataGridControl>
```

Binding to the Cuts ObservableCollection works well, but not the TotalCut. How do I bind the TotalCut [Intentionally written in all caps above] to that same column?
Using two columns is possible, but will not be pretty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forget the XCeed DataGridControl and welcome to standard DataGrid. Just use the DataGridTemplateColumn there.

The other alternative is just to use two columns in XCeed DataGridControl which is not preety.

Comment: seriously! why do they have to make it so damn complicated. easy migration from the regular DataGrid should have been a priority but this FieldName nonsense just isn't making any sense to me

Comment: @Simon_Weaver DataGridControl was there before DataGrid

Comment: :) standard DataGrid is extremely slow for large datagrids, I think this is main reason someone want to use exceed

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do - provide your own cell editor and CellTemplate, which will bind to corresponding properties. Here's my working solution:

```
    <xcdg:DataGridControl AutoCreateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <xcdg:DataGridControl.View>
        <xcdg:TableflowView ScrollingAnimationDuration="0" ContainerHeight="44"/>
    </xcdg:DataGridControl.View>
    <xcdg:DataGridControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="EditDataTemplate"  DataType="wpfApplication1:State">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Post}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ReadDataTemplate"  DataType="wpfApplication1:State">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding Path=Post}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </xcdg:DataGridControl.Resources>
    <xcdg:DataGridControl.Columns>
        <xcdg:Column FieldName="Zip" Title="Zip"/>
        <xcdg:Column FieldName="Stat" Title="Zip2"
                     CellContentTemplate="{StaticResource ReadDataTemplate}">
            <xcdg:Column.CellEditor>
                <xcdg:CellEditor EditTemplate="{StaticResource EditDataTemplate}"/>
            </xcdg:Column.CellEditor>
        </xcdg:Column>    
    </xcdg:DataGridControl.Columns>
</xcdg:DataGridControl>
```

and codebehind of "data object":

```
public class User
{
    private string _zip;

    public string Zip
    {
        get { return _zip; }
        set
        {
            _zip = value;
            Stat = new State();
            Stat.Name = "stat: " + value;
        }
    }

    public State Stat { get; set; }
}

public class State
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Post { get; set; }
}
```

[Entire solution code](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6Tey4prC11RUkJPc3BsRFc0QXc/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I'm sorry that i came back only after so long time. But you misunderstood the problem. What i wanted to put into the column was not the aggregated properties in the "State" object, but another properties on the same level with the "State" properties. The DataGridControl only have 1 "FieldName" for binding, thus disallow binding multiple properties into one column.

Comment: you can access any property via method I've described (using datatemplate)

Comment: @Shcherban that's the thing. the DataContext of the ContentTemplate is the value of the Bound Field and nothing more.

Even sadder is that you can't get to the DataRow via RelativeSource.

Comment: Well, i guess you can try setting '.' as bound field's name for column, that should resolve dataContext to entire object. At least standard wpf's binding works that way.