# Bind id field to tag of image inside xceed datagrid

Tags: wpf, xceed, xceed-datagrid

I want to bind `Id` field to tag of Image which inside column of Xceed DataGrid.

```
<xcdg:Column FieldName="D" Title="Delete" Width="50" CellHorizontalContentAlignment="Center" CellVerticalContentAlignment="Center">
    <xcdg:Column.CellContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{StaticResource imgDelete}" Tag="{Binding Id}" Width="16" Height="16" Cursor="Hand" 
                   x:Name="imgEdit" MouseLeftButtonUp="imgDelete_MouseLeftButtonUp" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Edit" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </xcdg:Column.CellContentTemplate>
</xcdg:Column>
```

But in event handler I am getting Tag as null:

```
private void imgDelete_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    AreaId = Convert.ToInt32((sender as Image).Tag);
    catch (Exception en)
}
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/15445099/1271037 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/20204275/1271037

Comment: From where this `Id` is coming?

Comment: Also check output window if there are any binding errors logged in it.

Comment: @RohitVats It is property inside the Observable Collection bound to datagrid.

Comment: See output window. Do you see any binding error reported there?

Comment: @RohitVats Yes. 'D' property not found on 'object' ''Area' (HashCode=3791685)'. BindingExpression:Path=E; DataItem='Area' (HashCode=3791685); target element is 'DataCell' (Name=''); target property is 'Content' (type 'Object').
How can I have two or more fields referring to same property 'id' in exceed datagrid? I gave fieldname as 'D' because it is not allowing me to use 'Id' as fieldname as I have it for another column. And I also want to bind Id to Tag of Image inside my column as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this as,
    


I put it inside Column definition and then used,